# What is the c# equiv of "object < object"?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have some very old VB.Net code that is:

```
 Private Function Min(ByVal A As Object, ByVal B As Object) As Object
            If A Is DBNull.Value Or B Is DBNull.Value Then Return DBNull.Value
            If A < B Then Return A Else Return B
        End Function
```

No worries. The compiler eats it.... and asks for more. But when converting to C#:

```
    private object Min(object A, object B)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(A, DBNull.Value) | object.ReferenceEquals(B, DBNull.Value))
            return DBNull.Value;
        return A < B ? A : B;
    }
```

Compiler chokes on it with error message :

```
Cannot apply operator '<' with operands of object and object
```

So, what the dilly yo?

Comment: The question is why the VB code compiles.

Comment: Well you _could_ type `A` and `B` to `dynamic` and let the code at runtime evaluate what to do with the `<` operator...

Comment: Oh, really...?? More Microsoft.VisualBasic super-specialness no doubt.

Comment: Is this supposed to be [Math.Min()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bw740h.aspx)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code only works in VB because you are using `Option Strict Off`. In general this is **incredibly bad practice**. Well, it’s old code as you say. In modern code (be it VB or C#) you’d use generics or/and interfaces. The code cannot be translated to generics directly due to the `DBNull` but here’s what a generic approach would look like in VB (without the `DBNull` check):

```vb
Function Min(Of T As IComparable(Of T))(a As T, b as T) As T
    Return If(a.CompareTo(b) < 0, a, b)
End Function
```

Coming back to your code, you can simply cast the two arguments to `IComparable` after ensuring that they’re not `DBNull`, and then do the equivalent:

```
private object Min(object A, object B)
{
    if (A == DBNull.Value || B == DBNull.Value)
        return DBNull.Value;
    return ((IComparable) A).CompareTo(B) < 0 ? A : B;
}
```

(For completeness’ sake, [C# 4 has the `dynamic` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) which allows the moral equivalent of the old VB code, namely deferring method dispatch to runtime. However, I don’t think that’s the most straightforward solution here, and I generally prefer to have as much statically checked type information as possible.)

Comment: Nice. Option Strict is not explicitly set to Off  but there is no Option Strict On at the top of the VB code file and the project file has Build setting of "custom" for Option Strict. So according to Google this means VB.Net is defaulting to Option Strict Off as per yours and other answers. Your IComparable suggestion in C# satisfies the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This page explains how the < operator behaves (including when applied to two objects like your case).

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey92b0t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (see "Typeless Programming with Relational Comparison Operators" section).

Like Konrad Rudolph suggested, the best way to translate it to C# is to use IComparable however, I guess that in your case, you could simply use Math.Min() if you are comparing numbers since it has no sense to apply this operator to objects (VB compiles it but throws an exception like said in the above link).

Comment: I "think" so . It's in a DatasetHelper class so not absolutely sure we're dealing strictly with numbers. Test will obviously reveal that. I just thought it was interesting.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to write a generic method where you can enforce the type to implement `IComparable`.

```
   public object Min<T>(T A, T B)
      where T: IComparable
   {
      if (object.ReferenceEquals(A, DBNull.Value) | 
          object.ReferenceEquals(B, DBNull.Value))
         return DBNull.Value;
      return A.CompareTo(B) < 0 ? A : B;
   }
```

Comment: That code won’t work (except for `T` = `object`) because no other type can contain a `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 0):

In vb if you have explicit off and strict off the compiler eats many things. In c# such thing does not exist, as far as i know.

Comment: I think we are all looking for something more precise than that.

Comment: Oh no just checked. Option Strict is not included in the code file. Forgetting VB can it be set as default somewhere in project file>?

Comment: Ok then, then turn on strict  and explicit  and try to compile.

Comment: Yes, try flicking random switches until you get something that works. Then move on none the wiser.

Comment: @kostas ch Strict not set, but Option Explicit is on and compiles.

Comment: Dear  rism this you have to set on the start of the class, i do not remember where else. Ithink you can set it and on project some where but i do not remember.

Comment: Mr  Chris Sinclair i would like to left these ironic comments for another time. Here we are to help  rism.

Comment: @kostasch. We are here to help, something that this answer fails to do. At the very best this might be a comment.

Comment: I disagree that this answer fails. But anyway you know better.

Comment: kostas ch.: I'd interpret the question as »What do I need to do in C# to do the same thing as the VB code above?« instead of »What do I need to do in VB to make that code not compile?« (which is what you seem to be aiming at).

Comment: I was aiming to remind that vb is much open with these restriction of and somethings may be compiled in vb and not in c#. Comparison between objects cannot occur BUT in vb it can with explicit off and strict off. This answer  will help to remember. But anyway. Lets continue and end this. Thamk you all people.

Comment: kostas was helpful, even if deemed OT/reversal of idea. It was something I overlooked. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't use comparison operators on the objects. Please make sure you pass the strings as parameters.

Comment: Apparently you can use comparison operators on objects in VB.

Comment: If I saw that code though I'd have literally no idea what it was doing. Strings as parameters is the way to go, if they are strings.

Comment: SLC: That depends on how it's interpreted by VB in that case. E.g. when you can pass numbers and the result is like expected then strings won't work like that.

Comment: @SLC I rather imagine that rism want the C# code to do what the VB code does. In which has having an idea what the VB code does it what this question is all about.

Comment: O.k so it makes sense to me that c# rejects it. I will "assume" it's some VB project setting somewhere outside code file that is allowing the compilation; since it all goes to the same MSIL it cant be "allowed" in one and not the other.

Comment: @rism "It all goes to the same MSIL". The IL that is produced depends on the language definition for the comparison operators. So you need to know what those operators mean for object.

Comment: @David Heffernan Since I cant compile the c# I cant directly compare. I suppose I could set a breakpoint at look at the dissembler of the VB but since I cant read assembly I really have not idea of what Im looking at and therefore wouldn't know what VB is actually doing under the covers. Unless there is an easy way to hunt for that method in IL. I actually thought it was all the same IL post compilation? So theres something i didn't know.

Comment: @rism I'm sure someone knows what VB does. I asked this question to find out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962674/what-do-the-relational-operators-mean-for-object-operands

Comment: @David Heffernan : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962674/what-do-the-relational-operators-mean-for-object-operands

Good one..:)