# What do the relational operators mean for object operands?

Tags: vb.net

*This question inspired by: [What is the c# equiv of "object < object"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962259/what-is-the-c-sharp-equiv-of-object-object)*

In the `Option Strict Off` mode the following code compiles:

```
Function Foo(ByVal O1 As Object, ByVal O2 As Object)
    Return O1 < O2
End Function
```

My question is what the relational operators mean when the operands are of type `Object`. I've downloaded the VB Language Specification, and looked at the VB Language Reference, and can find no information to explain this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at section 6.2.2:

> Under strict semantics, the following are disallowed:
>
> - Narrowing conversions without an explicit cast operator.
> - Late binding.
> - Operations on type Object other than TypeOf...Is, Is, and IsNot.
> - Omitting the As clause in a declaration that does not have an inferred type.

With `Option Strict Off`, VB simply uses late binding for method resolution. More information is given in [section 11.3: “Late-bound expressions”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712047%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).